# Given positive integers $n, k, i,$ prove $\binom{n}{k} = \sum_{j=i}^{n-k+i}\binom{j-i}{i-1}\binom{n-j}{k-i}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to solve this challenge question, but I cannot seem to figure out how to approach this:

Given $n, k,$ and $i$ positive integers with $1 \leq i \leq k \leq n$, $$\binom{n}{k} = \sum_{j=i}^{n-k+i}\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-j}{k-i}$$

I figured the LHS count the ways of creating a binary string with $k\ 0$'s and $n - k\ 1$'s, the RHS must partition that in some way, but I don't know how to go from there.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: ok, I edited it.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  Try making some examples with small $i,k,n$ to see if you can develop it.  I don't know if this will work; just a suggestion.

Comment: I did try it, I can see how it works with k = 1, because then i = 1, but it gets weird in the other examples

Comment: It doesn't seem to be true.  When $i=2,k=3,n=5$ I get $$\binom53=\sum_{j=2}^3\binom{j-2}{1}\binom{5-j}{1}=\binom01\binom31+\binom11\binom21\implies10=2$$  Have I made an error?

Comment: It looks like it is only true for $i=1$ see https://www.geogebra.org/classic/c4tb4a8t

Comment: Perhaps there's a typo somewhere.  Should one of the $i$'s in the formula be a $1$?

Comment: That's it ! the first binomial coefficient on the RHS should be $\binom {j-1}{i-1}$

Comment: Yes, my bad guys edited now :(

Comment: Should the upper limit of the summation be $n - k + i + 1$?

Comment: It says n - k + i

Comment: Yes, OK thanks - it originally read $n - k + 1$. I've posted a combinatorial proof of this fact below.

Comment: Thank you, yes it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity (which was originally in the question)
$${n \choose k} = \sum_{j = i}^{n - k + 1} {j - 1 \choose i - 1}{n - j \choose k - i}$$
is not true. You can basically take any values of $n, k,$ and $i$ with $1 \leq i \leq k \leq n$ and see this is not true.

Here is a combinatorial proof of the following identity, which is what I believe what you meant:
$${n \choose k} = \sum_{j = i}^{n - k + i} {j - 1 \choose i - 1}{n - j \choose k - i}$$

We will use an argument counting the number of $n$-bit bitstrings with $k$ zeroes, which is clearly ${n \choose k}$. From here, we will number the bits of an $n$-bit bitstring from left to right as $1$ to $n$.

The right-hand side can be interpreted as follows. First choose some random number $1 \leq i \leq k$. Then, to choose a bitstring with $k$ zeroes and $n - k$ ones, choose some bit $j \geq i$ to be a dividing point, and set it to zero. Then, choose $i - 1$ bits of the $j - 1$ bits to the left of the dividing point to be zero, and choose $k - i$ bits to the right of the dividing point to be zero. Note that if we read the bitstring from left to right, the $i$th zero bit will be in the $j$th slot. This is the crucial observation that shows us we have counted every bitstring with $k$ zeroes exactly once. *If you want to think in terms of partitioning the bitstrings, the terms of the summation have partitioned these bitstrings into classes where the $i$th zero bit is in the $j$th slot.*

Note also that $j$ must be no more than $n - k + i$ (i.e. there must be at least $k - i$ bits to the right of the dividing point), since otherwise it will not be possible to choose $k - i$ bits from the right side of the dividing point to be zeroes. Similar logic shows why $j \geq i$ is also required (because otherwise it will not be possible to select $i - 1$ bits to the left of $j$). *In other words, the $i$th zero bit in a bitstring of $k$ zeroes lies between bit $i$ and bit $n - k + i$.*

Note also that the condition $i \leq k$ is crucial, because if $i \geq k + 1$, then our procedure will have chosen at least $k$ zero bits to the left of the dividing point, and will have tried to select a negative number of zero bits to the right of the dividing point, which is clearly impossible. We must select a positive number of bits on each side of the dividing point. *In other words, there cannot exist an $i$th zero (reading from left to right) in a bitstring with $k$ zeroes unless $i \leq k$.*

So this procedure will work for all $1 \leq i \leq k$ as given in the question, and summing over the allowed values of $j$ for any fixed $i$, we get that
$${n \choose k} = \sum_{j = i}^{n - k + i} {j - 1 \choose i - 1}{n - j \choose k - i}$$
as desired. $\square$

Comment: This is a brilliant argument, and correct in every detail except that there are $(n-j)$ bits to the right of the dividing point, not $(n-i)$, so you have in fact demonstrated the correctness of the assertion .
$$\binom{n}{k} = \sum_{j=i}^{n-k+i}\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-j}{k-i}  $$

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the answer, thankfully that is what the OP intended and I just had a typo in the solution :)